# CSS to combine 2 colors for bootstrap badge

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to have combination of 2 colors for bootstrap badge. I dont want to mix 2 colors instead want to do something like this:

[image]

This is the first time I am having this kind of requirement. So completely not sure how to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have extracted the important part of the code that @Marvin put up at W3Schools' TryIt:

```
.badge {
  color: black;
  background: orange;
  border: 5px solid red;
  padding: 0 5px;
}
```

What you want to do is set the text color and background, and set a different color for the border, with an appropriate thickness.

You should look at the whole thing at his link, http://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=FAQVDL441G2K

**Working Example:**

```css
span.badge {
  color: black;
  background: orange;
  border: 5px solid red;
  padding: 0 5px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container">
  <span class="badge">2B</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the edit! Can you point me to some doc here on SO describing how to create a runnable snippit like you did?

Answer (score 2):

You can try this:

```css
.label {
  border-radius: 1.25em !important;
}

.label-warning {
  padding: 0.1em 0.8em !important;
  color: black !important;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<body>
<span class="label label-danger"><span class="label label-warning">28</span></span>
</body>
```

Hope this helps!